# MongoDB aggregation: any value of $exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to leverage MongoDB aggregation for a RESTful api, but got stuck with the following case. Suppose, I have `Subscriptions` model, which looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
  cancelled: Date
});
```

This `cancelled` property can be either `undefined`, if the subscription is active, or become a `Date` of the user's cancel action.

Now, I have a route `GET /me/subscriptions`, which aggregates subscriptions and has an optional query parameter: `cancelled=true` (show only cancelled) or `cancelled=false` (show only active). If not specified, should return any subscription (active or cancelled).

```
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  Subscription = require('../../models/subscription');

router.get('/me/subscriptions', function(req, res, next) {
  var cancelled = req.query.cancelled === 'true' ? { $exists: true } :
    req.query.cancelled === 'false' ? { $exists: false } :
    { $exists: { $or: [ true, false ] } }; // wrong logic here

  return Subscription.aggregate([
      { $match: { user: req.user._id, cancelled: cancelled }},
      { $project: {
        // ...
      }}
    ])
    .exec()
    // ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

It works perfectly if I pass the above mentioned query parameter, but fails to find models if no parameter is specified (or if it is not equal to either `true` or `false`). I have tried lots of stuff instead of the wrong line (in the `$match` pipeline):

```
cancelled: {}
cancelled: void 0
cancelled: { $exists: { $or: [ true, false ] } }
cancelled: { $exists: { $in: [ true, false ] } }
cancelled: { $exists: [ true, false ] } // obviously wrong, but hey
cancelled: null // obviously wrong, too
cancelled: { $or: [ { $exists: false }, { $exists: true } ] } // can't use $or here, but still, hey
```

The only solution is see now is something like this, comparing against a value which is not `undefined` and not of type `Date`, but it seems way too hacky.

```
cancelled: { $ne: 'some-impossible-value' }
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think a little tweaking will satisfy the condition as you want.**

```
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  Subscription = require('../../models/subscription');

router.get('/me/subscriptions', function(req, res, next) {
  var match_query = {user: req.user._id};

  if (req.query.cancelled === 'true') {
      match_query.cancelled = {$exists:true};
  } else if(req.query.cancelled === 'false') {
      match_query.cancelled = {$exists:false};
  }

  return Subscription.aggregate([
      { $match: match_query},
      { $project: {
        // ...
      }}
    ])
    .exec()
    // ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

You don't need to add { $exists: { $or: [ true, false ] } , just don't add anything to query if you don't get true or false.

I haven't checked code for syntax error, but logically it will work.

Comment: The solution is all right, but I tried to avoid that `if-then-else` stuff for the sake of brevity. Thanks.

Comment: I've combined your answer with the one from @chridam: `var match = { user: req.user._id }; if ([ 'true', 'false' ].indexOf(req.query.cancelled) !== -1) match.cancelled = { $exists: JSON.parse(req.query.cancelled) };`

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure the **`$match`** pipeline as follows (requires installing the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library):

```
router.get('/me/subscriptions', function(req, res, next) {
    var match = {
        "$match": {
            "user": req.user._id,
            "cancelled": {}
        }
    };

    if (req.query.cancelled === 'true' || req.query.cancelled === 'false') {
        match["$match"]["cancelled"]["$exists"] = JSON.parse(req.query.cancelled);
    } else if(moment(req.query.cancelled, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()){
        match["$match"]["cancelled"] = moment(req.query.cancelled).toDate();
    }
    else {
        match["$match"]["cancelled"]["$exists"] = false;
    }       

    return Subscription.aggregate([match,
        { "$project": {
          // ...
        }}
    ]).exec()
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know if it's a useful thing to query a subscription based on a date with milliseconds, though :D You can use dot-syntax, by the way, i.e. `match.$match.cancelled.$exists = true`.